# Can unquoted SoapAction HTTP header cause issues in web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, request-headers

I make a SOAP call to a web service which then shows these errors (info/warning really, I think) in the logs:

```
INFO: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: myAction
Sep 28, 2016 7:13:54 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter fixQuotesAroundSoapAction
```

Could this warning cause actual issues? Or does the fixQuotesAroundSoapAction method fix the issue when it sees it? I'm wondering if seeing these two lines in the logs should be concerning or can I ignore them?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter class, there is a method named "fixQuotesAroundSoapAction" with logic ,

if SOAPAction is not null and it does not start with double quote and end with double quote, it logs the mentioned warning and fix by adding double quote  to start and end of the SOAPAction string.

You can ignore or notify the Web Service provider about SOAPAction http header.

Here is the method,

```
private String fixQuotesAroundSoapAction(String soapAction) {
    if(soapAction == null || soapAction.startsWith("\"") && soapAction.endsWith("\"")) {
        return soapAction;
    } else {
        LOGGER.warning("Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: " + soapAction);
        String fixedSoapAction = soapAction;
        if(!soapAction.startsWith("\"")) {
            fixedSoapAction = "\"" + soapAction;
        }

        if(!soapAction.endsWith("\"")) {
            fixedSoapAction = fixedSoapAction + "\"";
        }

        return fixedSoapAction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you uses Log4J, try https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jul.

Add this to code:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager");
```

Add this to xml configuration file

```
<Loggers>
...
   <Logger name="com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" level="OFF"> 
   </Logger>
...
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a simple problem where you do not give a quote (") String in your SOAPAction HTTPHeader. Just put String `SOAPAction = "\"myAction\""` .  This " will add quotes to your HTTPHeader and the irritating warning will gone forever.